# What does "Copying Windows files" do during Windows 10 installation?

Tags: windows-10, installation, windows-installation

The first step is named "Copying Windows files" in Windows 10 installation (via DVD drive). However it always completes in the blink of an eye. What exactly is it, and why does it go so quickly?

[image]

Comment: I would imagine it's extracting compress files.  A log file should exist.